# How does uploading work in BitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, c++, sockets

I'm building a BitTorrent client in C++ by following this https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification.

I am able to download pieces from peers successfully. I have a couple of questions regarding uploading.

1. I know that the client becomes part of the peer list of the tracker when we first make an announce to the tracker,but how do the other peers know what port to connect to when connecting to my client?
2. After I connect to a peer, do I have keep listening to the peer? In case it wants to request some data or send other messages.
3. I should also listen for connections with other peers, that want to download data from my client, am I right in assuming this?

Comment: This question is probably more suited to StackOverflow site.

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so]. If you are blocked from asking questions there then please read [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: @Mokubai  This is just a joke, I am blocked from asking questions there. Reading the linked article will not help me  get my ability to ask questions there. Now I am getting downvoted here, can't wait to lose the privileges here too.

Comment: @Mokubai I have done sufficient research regarding the above question. where I am supposed to ask a question if not on a forum?. I am here to learn about the subject, not get a degree in "Asking questions".Yes, sometimes you ask a poor question ,but taking away someone's ability to ask a question on a 'question-answer' website is probably the dumbest thing ever . Why don't the mods write all the questions to ever exist so that it will finally be to their liking. If you don't want learners on these forums, then why don't you bans new users, oh wait, Stackoverflow has essentially done that.

Comment: @Mokubai I wish I could down-vote Stackoverflow as a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The port-info should be part of the announce.
2. Not really. You initiate the connection. The peers answers to your request, but it won't volunteer information all by itself, so you don't have to listen for it.
3. Yes. Strictly speaking you don't have to if you only want to download and not upload, but most other clients will quickly notice that and will refuse to let you download from them if you don't give anything in return.
   Freeloading is strongly frowned upon in torrent circles.